# Prove $QAQ^T$ is an isomorphism iff Q is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S_Q: V \to V$ be the linear transformation defined by $S_Q(A)=QAQ^T$ for all $A \in V$.

I want to prove that $S_Q$ is an isomorphism if and only if Q is invertible.

I'm not sure how exactly to approach this proof from either direction. I know that an isomorphism is a bijective linear transformation, and that $S_Q(A)$ inverse is $Q^T$ inverse times A inverse times Q inverse. I'm not really sure how to prove the facts though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $Q$ is invertible, then so is $Q^\top$, and the inverse must be
$$S_Q^{-1}(B) = Q^{-1} B (Q^\top)^{-1}.$$
You can verify this by showing $S_Q(S_Q^{-1}(B)) = B$ and $S_Q^{-1}(S_Q(A)) = A$.

If $Q$ is not invertible, then it must have a non-trivial nullspace. That is, there must be some non-zero column vector $v$ such that $Qv = 0$. Let $A$ be the matrix formed by putting $v$ in all the columns. Then $QA = 0$, and hence
$$S_Q(A) = QAQ^\top = 0Q^\top = 0.$$
Since $v \neq 0$, we have $A \neq 0$, so $S_Q$ is not injective and hence not invertible.

Comment: How did you get the first expression that $S_Q^{-1}(B) = Q^{-1} B (Q^\top)^{-1}$? Thanks

Comment: Well, it just seemed like the "obvious" way of undoing $S_Q$. Since $S_Q$ multiplies a matrix on the left and the right by invertible matrices, it seemed obvious that the inverse would multiply a matrix by the inverse of these matrices. You could also solve the equation $B = S_Q(A)$ for $A$, and get much the same result.